# Excel: How do I link to an external workbook always in the same directory?

Tags: excel, hyperlink, external

I have file A.xlsx that has lookups to an external workbook called data.xlsx. data.xlsx is generated by a script so always has the name data.xlsx and is generated in various places.

I want to copy A to different places and always have the formula inside the workbook link to the data.xlsx generated in the same directory (as mentioned, data.xlsx is a file generated by a script so has different data inside each time).

My formula is something like this: 
=IFERROR(INDEX('C:\Users\andrew\Test1[data.xlsx]sheet1'!$B$2:$AG$36, MATCH($C...

but this links to the specific file and gives me trouble when I copy A.xlsx to different places (it effectively remembers the path to the original data.xlsx).

Is there a "CurrentDir" kind of way to do this, e.g. =IFERROR(INDEX('[CurrentDir][data.xlsx]sheet1'!$B$2:$AG...

so that I will always read a file data.xlsx that is in the same directory as A.xlsx?

Answer (score 0):

Current Dir is ./
'C:\Users\andrew\Test1[data.xlsx]sheet1'!$B$2:$AG$36, MATCH($C...

should be :
'[data.xlsx]sheet1'!$B$2:$AG$36, MATCH($C...

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I change the formula it opens file explorer and asks me to locate a file.

Comment: use only [data.xlsx] it will look for it in the current directory of the current file.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/328440/description-of-link-management-and-storage-in-excel

Comment: try it without any path before the file name
have a loo at this link 
http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/showthread.php?t=257933